# Testing page titles of all pages in an app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

So I recently implemented a bit of code that assigns page titles to the pages in my app via the controller.

**In the controller:**

```
def index
    @page_title = "My Awesome Index Page!"
end
```

**In the main layout:**

```
<title><%= @page_title ? "#{@page_title} - Website Name" : "Website Name" %></title>
```

The goal is to give pages names like "My Awesome Index Page! - Website Name", but in the case that @page_title is not defined in the controller, it just defaults to "Website Name"

Now to the issue. This app has somewhere on the order of 250 pages. I would like some sort of automated way to test all the pages and make sure that I haven't missed any. Ideally I would like to have an automated test that hits every page so that when future pages are added, if @page_title is not defined, the test will fail and alert me that the new page needs to have its page_title set.

Alternatively, it would be great to at least have a script of some kind that I could run that hits each page in the app and returns a list of the page titles or something. That way I can at least make sure that I got every one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I don't have an answer to your question but I use a different approach.

Usually best practice is to test exactly one thing at once and it has to be important. If it would be important to me to have a page title I would write a test for each title in question and so following the same approach as Micheal Hartl in his [Rails Tutorial](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/rails-flavored-ruby#code-title_helper)

I definitly didn't write 250 specs only for page titles yet. But I never had the requirements.

Answer (score 0):

My approach would be to use `I18n`, so you can record all titles in a locale file */config/locales/titles.yml*. It allow you to group all titles in one single file, making easy to see what you are doing. It also have the advantage to keep your controller clean.

Then to get your title you could use `controller_name` and `action_name` values to retrieve the text from the locale file. Wrapped in a helper method:

**Helper method**

```
# This is pseudo code, I did not test it, it is only to demonstrate the approach
# But it should work :)
def html_title
  title = I18n.translate! "#{controller_name}.#{action_name}"
  content_tag :title, title
end
```

**titles.yml**

```
en:
  users:
    index: 'Here you go with the list of awesome users'
    show: 'Showing an awesome user record'
```

**Solution 1:**

As you can see I use `I18n.translate!` with a bang!, this will raise an exception if the translation is not found in your locale file: each title that you forgot to define will raise an exception.

As for the testing I would be using capybara to browse all pages and check that there is no error.

**Solution 2:**

If you don't want the exception you can use `:default` option of `translate` like this:

```
def html_title
  title = I18n.translate "#{controller_name}.#{action_name}", default: 'My awesome default title'
  content_tag :title, title
end
```

Note that I am not using the bang anymore. Then your Capybara scan all your pages and ensure that the title is not strictly equal to 'My awesome default title'